# Explanation of Russian assorted saints and festivities icon "Plenka"

Tags: eastern-orthodox, iconography

Monastery/production company Sofrino supplies icon "Plenka" of assorted saints and festivities:

[image: ИКОНА НА ДЕРЕВЯННОМ ПЛАНШЕТЕ 18Х24 ПЛЕНКА]

[ИКОНА НА ДЕРЕВЯННОМ ПЛАНШЕТЕ 18Х24 ПЛЕНКА](https://sofrino.ru/products/ikony-63/ikony_na_derevyannom_planshete-2358/ikona_na_derevyannom_planshete_18h24_plenka-3696/)

I have bought one in almost A4 format but still the writing is too small for understanding. Is there available explanation of this icon? I guess, it is quite standard icon and so there should be quite standard explanation?

Answer (score 3):

"Plenka" means "skin" or "membrane" in this context and refer to material covering the icon.

The icon itself called "all saints" and depicts major saints in order of their festive days during year. Twelve big sections correspond to months, starting from January. Big caption above the section is month name.

Small captions inside each section contain festive description or saint's name. Red letters on the left are church-slavonic digits - it is a day number in the month corresponding to saint/festive.

Answer (score 2):

This is great. As a rule of thumb, always buy icons larger than you think you'll need them.

So, this is a yearly Menaion icon. The Menaion is basically a book that tells you, for each month, what saints are celebrated on each day. Accordingly, this is an icon with a saint for every day. (We usually commemorate many, *many* saints on a given day. This also doesn't include stuff for movable feasts like Pascha.)

I'll point out a few big ones for you.

1. Circumcision of Jesus
2. Theophany (baptism of Jesus)
3. Presentation of Jesus into the Temple
4. Possibly the Forty Martyrs of Sebaste?
5. Annunciation
6. St. George
7. Ss. Constantine and Helen
8. *Possibly* the Synaxis of Archangel Gabriel?
9. Seven Sleepers of Ephesus
10. Transfiguration of Christ
11. Dormition of the Theotokos
12. Beheading of John the Baptist
13. Nativity of the Theotokos
14. Exaltation of the Cross
15. Intercession of the Theotokos
16. *Possibly* the Synaxis of Archangel Michael?
17. Presentation of the Theotokos
18. Nativity of Christ
19. Synaxis of the Theotokos

[image]